# Bayes classifier program to predict the class of give information in java using Jtable

Tags: java, jtable, naivebayes

Naive Bayes program to predict the work type for a person with following parameters: age: 30,Qualication: MTech, Experience: 8..

```
    WorkType       Age     Qualication     Experience

   Consultancy     30       Ph.D.             9
    Service        21       MTech.            1
    Research       26       MTech.            2
    Service        28       BTech.            10
    Consultancy    40       MTech.            14
    Research       35       Ph.D.             10
    Research       27       BTech.             6
    Service        32       MTech.             9
    Consultancy    45       Btech.            17
    Research       36       Ph.D.              7

    package try2;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class bayes  
    {
        JFrame frame;
        JTable table;
        JPanel panel;
        JScrollPane tableContainer;

        int i,j;
        int countC=0,countR=0,countS=0;
        int count=0;
        int[] CAge=new int[3];


        public bayes()
        {
              frame = new JFrame("JTable Test Display");

              panel = new JPanel();
              panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
             String row[][]={{"consultancy","30","phd","9"},  
                   {"service","21","mtech","1"}              ,
                {"research","26","mtech","2"},{"service","28","btech","10"},
                {"consultancy","40","mtech","14"},{"research","35","phd","10"},
                {"research","27","btech","6"},{"service","32","mtech","9"},
                {"consultancy","45","btech","17"},{"research","36","phd","7"}};

        String column[]={"job","age","qualification","experience"};
        table=new JTable(row,column);

         tableContainer = new JScrollPane(table);

        panel.add(tableContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);



        //work type count
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(table.getValueAt(i,0)=="consultancy")
            {
                countC++;
            }
            if(table.getValueAt(i,0)=="research")
            {
                countR++;
            }
            if(table.getValueAt(i,0)=="service")
            {
                countS++;
            }
        }


        //consultancy age count
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)

        {
  ***if(((table.getValueAt(i, 0))=="consultancy") && ((Integer.parseInt((String)table.getValueAt(i, 1))>=20) || (Integer.parseInt((String)table.getValueAt(i, 1))<=30)) )***
            {
              count++;  
            }
```

The problem with above code is that I'm not able to compare the age column values with numbers.I tried to convert the values into int using intparse() function but still its not working.the line is marked with *** in above given code.please help me.it is giving error that it cannot convert object type to integer

Comment: I'm sorry actually I got confused with typecasting ie between toint() and inparse()....but when I 'm running code now and it is giving incorrect count  it is giving 3   but it should give 1;;; ie worker with consultancy type and age inbetween 20 to 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is in the condition:

```
((Integer.parseInt((String) table.getValueAt(i, 1)) >= 20) || (Integer.parseInt((String) table.getValueAt(i, 1)) <= 30))
```

this evaluates always to true and so the count is incorrect. If you want to count only people with age between 20 and 30 you should use an AND operator:

```
((Integer.parseInt((String) table.getValueAt(i, 1)) >= 20) && (Integer.parseInt((String) table.getValueAt(i, 1)) <= 30))
```

Comment: yeah..its correct . this condition is giving true for all workers having worktype consultancy...how to do it??

Comment: yeah..it is comparing  all the rows for age column..only i variable is iterating the column value is constant ie 1.